# Magento 1.9 - in onepage.phtml $_stepInfo['label'] - where is ["label"] coming from?

Tags: magento-1.9

In frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage.phtml there is a foreach loop

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
```

which renders the checkout steps

```
<h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
```

As fas as I know the getSteps() comes from app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php

```
public function getSteps()
{
    $steps = array();
    $stepCodes = $this->_getStepCodes();

    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $stepCodes = array_diff($stepCodes, array('login'));
    }

    foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
        $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
    }

    return $steps;
}
```

which extends to the class in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
```

But where is the ["label"] part coming from? Or how could I add an additional step to the checkout as well as the correct new label for it?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` of each step are set in the `_construct` of each step block.

For example, look at the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Login::_construct`. You will see :

```
$this->getCheckout()->setStepData('login', array('label'=>Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Checkout Method'), 'allow'=>true));
```

You will find the same logic in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing`, `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping`, `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method`, `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment` and finally `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review`.

Adding an additional step requires a lot of job : PHP obviously but a lot of javascript updates too : see `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` and you will find hard coded step names.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I actually don't need a new step, only a new label. Maybe I can figure out a work around, otherwise I just have to hard code a new label to my template I guess. Thank you.